# Why can't I schedule a fixed delay task using scheduler

Tags: java, mysql, scheduled-tasks, executorservice

I want to use Java's `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule a delayed service to delete some rows in the database given the expiration date. But I found that even after the specified expiration date, the row in the database is not deleted. So the schedule task is not executed. My code is as follows:

```
public int addNewGroup(final String groupName, Category category,
        Timestamp expireDate) {

    String sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO Groups (name, category, expireDate) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    int numRows = jdbcTemplate.update(sqlQuery, new Object[] { groupName,
            category.toString(), expireDate });

    //schedule the deleting temporary group task
    if (category == Category.temp) {
        final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        Runnable task = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String query = "DELETE FROM Groups WHERE name=?";
                jdbcTemplate.update(query, new Object[] {groupName});
            }
        };
        scheduler.schedule(task, expireDate.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }
    return numRows;
}
```

This is my test code to insert a record to the DB which has an expiration date:

```
public class StoregroupDaoTest {

    private StoregroupDao dao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
        dao = context.getBean(StoregroupDao.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAdd() {
        String groupName = "ABC";
        Category category = Category.temp;
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        Timestamp expireTime = new Timestamp(114, 8, 3, 16, 57, 0, 0);    //2014-09-03 16:57:00
        int numRows = dao.addNewGroup(groupName, category, expireTime);
    }

}
```

The record is inserted to the DB. It is expected to be deleted by the scheduled task given above after the expiration time. But after the specified expiration time, when I queried the DB, the record is still there and is not deleted. So it seems that the schedule task is not executed at all. What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonga,

The first thing that comes to my mind is to ensure that the ScheduledExecutor is properly being invoked and running when you expect it to run. I would first try to confirm this by changing your DELETE statement into a "INSERT" statement, and if you want, put in some output to your logger. Once you have verified this, I would try to run your query through MySQL workbench with the parameters you desire. Once this clears, I would try to log the parameters that are being fed to your ScheduledExecuter, and make sure they are as expected. Once you have verified all of these, your query should be executing as expected! :-)

Another way of approaching this problem is by using scheduled procedural calls. What you can do is have the procedure you've described above ported to your MySQL's PL, and have it run every n seconds. You'll be loosing visibility of the code by doing this, but it's also another neat way of running procedures every n seconds. The advantage to this, is that the ScheduledExecutor can have concurrency issues if it starts to become complex, and it's simply easier and more straight forward to use a MySQL procedure for this instead.

You can use mysql scheduler to run it each 5 seconds. You can find samples at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

You can schedule a stored procedure in MySQL in the following manner:

```
 CREATE EVENT myevent
     ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
     DO
      delete_rows_links();
```

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Hi Devarsh, thanks for your suggestions. I put some logging printout in the scheduler but it seems it is not running at all because upon expiration time, there is no printout at all. I also tried using the same DELETE query in my DB and it works fine. Using stored procedure is fine, but I really want to use Java code to remove the record. I don't know why the task scheduler doesn't run at all.

Comment: Hey Tonga, yep! That's usually the harry part with the ScheduledExecuter- making it run when you want it to :/ could you check out these tutorials http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.util.concurrent/ScheduledExecutorServicescheduleRunnablecommandlongdelayTimeUnitunit.htm and  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/scheduledexecutorservice.html ; make sure your thread pool size is large enough as well; please let me know what progress you make and if you have any other questions! :-)

Comment: I also printed out the fed parameter to the scheduler: `expireDate.getTime()`. It is correct in terms of milliseonds from epoch time. So really a puzzle.

Comment: did you try increasing your thread pool size of scheduler from 1 to 5?

Comment: yes, but it doesn't help. The scheduled task is still not invoked upon the delay time.

Comment: I think it might be beacuse of the expression 
"expireDate.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis()". What does this parameter correspond to? The time when you invoke the thread? If so, it should be the currentTime or a future time. The above expression will return sometime in the past.

Comment: According to the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)), this parameter is the delay from now to run the task. So `expireDate.getTime()-System.currentTimeMillis()` will get the delay time in milliseconds.

Comment: Hmm...okay. I think it might be beacuse it's never entering the "if" statement. This is beacuse if (category == Category.temp) is usually not used with non primitives; try: category.equals(Category.temp). Also try to debug the output of the "category.equals(Category.temp)" and make sure it's returning true; could you please do that and let me know what happens? Everything else seems fine; I checked out the javadoc and ran the code locally, and everything else seems fine

Comment: I tried adding some print code inside the if statement and it prints. So it goes into the if block, but the scheduled task never gets run after the specified delay time.

Comment: can you please put your latest code into a pastebin or gist; the scheduler seems to be working on my end, so i'm curious what's going on-on your end

Comment: Ooohh, I think i might know what your problem is. move "final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);" outside your method and make it a private. I believe what's happening is that when your test leaves the scope of the if statement and the method, the scheduler might be deleted. could you please try that?

Comment: I moved the scheduler block outside the if block and moved it into a private function, but it is still not executed. No idea why it does not run.

Comment: Hey tonga, don't move it into a private function, just make "final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);" into " private "final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);" - a global variable. I believe the compiler might be garbage collecting your scheduler because you exist the scope

Comment: Devarsh, thanks for your kind help. I changed it to a private member variable in my DAO class. But it still doesn't work. The reason is what you said: In my JUnit test, the DAO class instance dao already dies when the unit test is done. So the scheduler is not run. I edited my post. So how could I change my code to make the life time of the dao still alive after running the JUnit test?

Comment: Hey Tonga, definitely no worries! It's my pleasure!! :-) I would change your JUnit test to continue to run until your DAO class instance returns a success. This could be implemented by giving a callback to your future- the callback could give the status of your query like "completed" or "executed with error". And have your JUnit test continue to run until it receives a message from this callback. Do you want to give that a try?

Comment: Thanks a lot, Devarsh! I tried it and it indeed works! So the reason is really the lifetime of the scheduler is ended when the JUnit test is done. So the scheduler is not invoked even though I gave it a delay time.

Comment: Hey Tonga! Awesome!! So glad to hear it worked well! And it was really interesting learning about the lifetime of the scheduler; I'm sure this will save  both of us hours/days in the future! haha Hope you have a great week and weekend ahead! :0)

Comment: Hi Devarsh, really appreciate your patience and helpful suggestions. This is a great lesson for me that the JUnit standalone test need consider the lifetime of some scheduled task using executorservice like class.